# Second XSL template disables the first one

Tags: html, xml, xslt

The following template fixes the `img/src` attribute and is there since years:

```
<xsl:template match="xh:img/@src">
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="
            if( string-length(substring-before(substring-after(
                subsequence(parent::node()/following-sibling::comment(),1,1),'src=&quot;'),'.eps')) > 0 )
            then
                concat('images/',tokenize(concat(substring-before(substring-after(
                    subsequence(parent::node()/following-sibling::comment(),1,1),'src=&quot;'),'.eps'),'.png'),'/')[last()])
            else
                data(self::node())"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Now I added the following template to move `width` and `height` to `style`:

```
<xsl:template match="xh:img">
    <img style="width:{@width}; height:{@height};">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*[not(name()='width' or name()='height')]"/>
    </img>
</xsl:template>
```

The second one works but it "disables" the first one.
If I comment the second one, the first works.
Is there a way to merge them?

I really don't have experience with XSL so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using `xsl:copy-of` to copy attributes in the template matching `xh:img`. This will not apply any matching templates, but just copy them exactly.

Simply change to using `xsl:apply-templates`...

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(name()='width' or name()='height')]"/>
```

However, you might need to add an additional template to match attributes other than `src` should you wish them to still be created too.

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: It was so easy? I was trying to merge them... thanks, it works perfectly!